# Sum of column in pig apache

Tags: hadoop, foreach, sum, apache-pig

I have relation named ==> total
which i get after grouping a file

so if i use this command
grunt> describe total;

```
grunt> **total: {group: int,long}**

file date =>
(851,3)                                                                                                                                              
(1110,6)                                                                                                                                             
(1115,19)                                                                                                                                            
(1758,2)                                                                                                                                             
(,1)
```

So the problem is i want to calculate the sum of long colum which has to give 31
in the total.

i used this line.

```
show_total = FOREACH total_flights GENERATE SUM(group);
```

but it is giving error please guide me to do it right.

Comment: Post your entire script and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting?
Also,try this :

```
show_total = FOREACH total_flights GENERATE SUM(group.columnname);
```

Comment: SUM(group.long)

Comment: i also tried as you are telling but same error

Actually that is the main problem as you understand

that is result of grouping So=>  total: {group: int,long}

in relation===total 
colum is group
in this 
two number are there
like
(1110,6)
which is giving description as == total: {group: int,long}


and the error which it is giving most is

Please use an explicit cast



Thanks for helping

Comment: Try doing this:    show_total = FOREACH total_flights GENERATE SUM($1.$1);   This should solve..

Comment: can you paste the 'describe relationname' here?

Comment: total: {group: int,long}
Now 
using as count
grunt> describe count;                                                                                                                               
count: {group: int,long}

Answer (score 0):

```
show_total = FOREACH total_flights GENERATE SUM(group.$1) ;
```

or set the column name and try

```
show_total = FOREACH total_flights GENERATE SUM(group.columname) ;
```